# checkPropTypes.js:20 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `form` is marked as required in `LoginPage`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am stuck on same bug for 2 days now and I can t find fix. I was hoping somebody would help me out with this one. It seems that error is on  form: PropTypes.array.isRequired, in PropTypes but I don t get why. I mean I initialized state to empty array in formReducer. I would appreciate any help cause I just started Learning React and React-Redux is a bit overwhelming for me but I really want to learn it.

**loginPage**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as formAction from "../../redux/actions/formAction";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      visitor: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
      },
    };
    //this.updateVisitor = this.updateVisitor.bind(this);
  }

  updateVisitor(attr, event) {
    console.log(attr + " == " + event.target.value);

    const updatedVisitor = { ...this.state.visitor }; //ili je object assign vrati se na 27.47
    updatedVisitor[attr] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      visitor: updatedVisitor,
    });
  }

  register(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(formAction.insertID(this.state.visitor));
    console.log("REGISTER:" + JSON.stringify(this.state.visitor));
  }

  login(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("LOGIN:" + JSON.stringify(this.state.visitor));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.register.bind(this)}>
              <input
                onChange={this.updateVisitor.bind(this, "username")}
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Username"
              ></input>
              <br />

              <input
                onChange={this.updateVisitor.bind(this, "password")}
                className="form-control"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              ></input>

              <br />
              <button type="submit" value="save">
                Register
              </button>
            </form>

            <hr />

            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.login.bind(this)}>
              <input
                onChange={this.updateVisitor.bind(this, "username")}
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Username"
              ></input>

              <br />
              <input
                onChange={this.updateVisitor.bind(this, "password")}
                className="form-control"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              ></input>
              <br />

              <button type="submit" value="save">
                Log in
              </button>
              {this.props.form.map((Zasvaki) => (
                <div key={Zasvaki.username}>{Zasvaki.username}</div>
              ))}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  form: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    form: state.form,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage);
```

***configureStore***

```
import rootReducer from "./reducers/formReducer";
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from "redux-immutable-state-invariant";

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; //Add support for redux devtools
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant()))
  );
}
```

***formAction***

```
export function insertID(ID) {
  return { type: "INSERT_ID", ID: ID };
}
```

***formReducer***

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INSERT_ID":
      return [...state, { ...action.ID }]; //Vraca klonirani array sa svim prijasnjim stanima plus sa novim stanjem dodanim
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

***index.js //Combine reducer***

```
import form from "./formReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: form,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Maybe issue here is that `form` doesn't have value yet when the component is being initialized. If you remove `required` does it work or `form` is still undefined?

What do you get printed in console here?   do you see `form` set here immediately?
```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('form: ', state.form);
  return {
    form: state.form,
  };
}
```

Comment: When I remove isRequired I get this ```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```
and when I  console.log("form: ", state.form);
result is: form:  undefined
Is it then error in the reducer, cause I got form imported in rootReducer, and form reducer state is an empty array. And tbh I don t even get how I can get value from state.form I've done this by tutorial but I am adapting to my own app, so the part in MapStateToProps is the part I don t really understand tbh.

Comment: ok, I see. Let's try to debug it and first change `this.props.form.map((Zasvaki) => (` to `this.props.form && this.props.form.map((Zasvaki) => (`. Then I want you console log  `state` in `mapStateToProps `.   Also if you have your app on github post a link, so it's easier to see what's happening, and even run your app locally

Comment: Wow now it works and shows no error, i am so confused :P ?
the ```console.log(state);``` gets me: Array(0) as it should cause state is empty array right? Here is link to github without node_modules folder:https://github.com/carlotamburin/ez-kanban-board/tree/0.1 , i suspect you don' t need them? I would be grateful if you could just explain here what is happening so I can continue to move on. I am planning to connect form to database using tables not array so this was just a test that I stuck on for far to long. Thank you for your help man.

Comment: I mean the part where it should map passwords and username and print it doesn't work still. But form itself doesnt crash. But would like to fix all that. But when i console loge state it has all those inputs, so what s wrong then. Why map doesnt work like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reducer doesn't have name in your case, so when you assing values to the form just assign the whole state:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("there's no 'form' on the state: ", state.form); // undefined
  // looks like you need to assign whole state
  return { form: state };
}
```

and now you wont need to do `this.props.form &&` part in:

```
this.props.form && this.props.form.map((Zasvaki) => (
```

^^ that would fix your error, BUT what I really suggest you doing is to make redux state an object and actually assign the value you want to a property `form` in your case. So in reducer you will have something like this:

```
export default function formReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INSERT_ID":
      return {
        ...state,
        form: {
          ...action.ID
        }
      }
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      }
  }
}
```

Then in loginPage.js you would need following changes:

```
Auth.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // most likely you will not need an array of user names and passwords
  // change back to the array if otherwise
  form: PropTypes.shape({
    username: PropTypes.string,
    password: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { form: state.form };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Auth);
```

and in the html just display properties of the `form` you want to see:

```
{this.props.form && (
  <div key={this.props.form.username}>{this.props.form.password}</div>
)}
```

Comment: You are life saver. I will will implement these changes now and start moving on my next step after long time being stuck here. Thank you so much